# Date formatting not clear

Tags: php, datetime

Below code format for date is: `2017-12-02`
But how to replace this to be `02-12-2017`. Tried various solutions, but none is working so far.

```
<?php
if($result1->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['Date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Time']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Home']; ?> - <?php echo $row['Away']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Refer to PHP's [date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Date']));
echo $newDate;
```

Try this one or whichever field your date is stored. It will convert it to the format you need.

**Comment answer:**

for your case you can `echo` the value like this :

```
<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Date'])); ?>
```

You can simple replace the old value you were echoing and wanted to remove.

Comment: This looks like the thing i need...However where i have to put this in? In the TD field or?

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
$str = '2017-12-02';
$time = strtotime($str);
echo date('d-m-Y', $time);
```

edit: explanation: `strtotime` will convert a given string to a unix-timestamp, and `date` will return a formated date-string for the given timestamp. Be aware: `strtotime` expects the given string to comply with PHP date-formats, see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

For example:

```
var_dump(strtotime('2017-05-06')); //int(1494021600)
var_dump(strtotime('2017.05.06')); //bool(false)
```

As an alternative you could use the DateTime object. That would look like this:

```
echo (new \DateTime('2017-12-02'))->format('d-m-Y'); //02-12-2017
```

Comment: Please, add more information about what have you done and why. It will help for those who are learning.

Answer (score 0):

if you are aware of the structure of the date - the best way to handle situations like these is to use the `datetime` class

Try the code below

```
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['Date']);
echo $objDate->format('d-m-Y');
```